# Variables solving as Continuous instead of Binary

Tags: mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, pulp

I am trying to solve this problem where the LP variables are declared as binary, but the solution spits them out as Continuous.  There are a set of constraints where there are relations between the binary variables and continuous ones and I suspect this is where the issue is caused.  Any idea on how to fix this?

Here are the variables:

```
overtime = LpVariable.dicts("overtime",[(block,week,day,room) for block in blocks for week in weeks for day in days 
                                    for room in operating_rooms], cat='Continuous', lowBound = 0.0)
assignments = LpVariable.dicts("assignments",[(week,day,room,nurse,length) for week in weeks for day in days for room in 
                                              operating_rooms for nurse in nurses for length in shift_lengths], cat='Binary', lowBound = 0)
```

And here is the constraint:

```
for block in blocks:
for week in weeks:
    for day in days:
        for room in operating_rooms:
            prob += overtime[block,week,day,room] >= block_schedule.at[(block,week,day),room] * 2.5 - lpSum([assignments[week,day,room,nurse,length]*length for nurse in nurses for length in shift_lengths])
```

Assignments are solving as 0.57 etc instead of either 0 or 1.

Comment: I see two possibilities: (1) The solver does not support integer variables (2) the model was not solved to optimality (e.g. time limit, infeasibilitiies etc). It would be good to check the solver log.

Comment: As @ErwinKalvelagen has said I'd put my money on your problem being infeasible. After running solve try `print("Status: ", LpStatus[prob.status])` to check

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen The model is solving for an optimal solution according to the logs.  I am using CBC solver, which I believe is the default. 
 prob.solve(pulp.PULP_CBC_CMD(msg=True))
print("Status:", LpStatus[prob.status])
print(prob.objective.value())

Comment: Looks we need a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example